# What is .csv. file?

Tags: windows, file, kernel

I know what is .csv file. But today customer sent me a picture of .csv file. Does anyone know what is it? It seems a file for window kernel because you can't operate it.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZaZH.jpg)

Comment: Google it or use wikipedia

Comment: Try opening one in a text editor (e.g. Notepad) and see if it is comma-separated values.  A file extension of .csv does not mean that it **is** comma-separated values, nor does the lack of a .csv extension mean that it is **not** comma-separated values.  And a `.csv.` extension **might** be just someone accidentally putting an extra "." on the end.

Comment: Set your (customer's) Windows Explorer to *not* hide file extensions (google if not sure what that means). Then you'll probably see the full filename as `D100302.csv..whatever`. Open it in Notepad to see what's inside (do *not* double-click it).

Comment: @dxiv - it looks like Unix does allow files to end with a dot, so there is a good chance that the files were created on a Unix system.  But I agree with the concept of being paranoid until the files are **proven** safe.

Comment: It was set to show extension. And it can't be opened and be copied. @dxiv

Comment: Assuming the file exists with that dot-ending name, execute `type "\\?\E:\<full-path-here>\D100302.csv."` at a `cmd` prompt to see its contents. Replace `type` with `del` to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a regular .CSV file with a misspelled dot at the end. Just edit the name of the file and delete the last dot (so it reads .csv again). If windows ask if you are sure you want to change the file extension, select yes. Then you should be able to open your file.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow filenames ending in a `.` dot, so the end user couldn't create one by accident. You can try it in Explorer, Notepad etc. It *is* possible to create such files in more convoluted ways, but I wouldn't trust software that does that on purpose to obfuscate.